# Why non-equality on 1st index part causes "can not add condition on 2nd index part in range condition"?

Tags: mysql

From  the  PPT MySQL Optimizer Overview, we know that non-equality on 1st index part causes "can not add condition on 2nd index part in range condition", however equality on 1st index part causes "can add condition on 2nd index part in range condition" in page 24 and 23 , why  ?
https://www.slideshare.net/myxplain/con9169-pdf-91690001

Comment: I don't understand your question, what's not clear from the stated? Why it can add a condition if first part that has to be satisfied is true?

Comment: My question is why "can not add condition on 2nd index part in range condition" mentioned in the PPT page 24.

Comment: You're saying one thing in your question and another thing in your comment. I can't understand you (I'm not native English speaker either) so I hope someone comes along who can. Good luck to you!